# cakephp3 has many associtation returning null

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to set up a Has Many association between books and authors, however when pulling authors from the database the 'books' attribute is never defined. Giving me the following error:

`Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Template\Authors\index.ctp, line 6]`

My code so far:

src/Model/Authors.php

```
<?php
    class Author extends AppModel
    {
       var $name = 'Author';
       var $hasMany = 'Book';
    }
?>
```

src/Model/Books.php

```
<?php
class Book extends AppModel
{   var $name = 'Book';
    var $belongsTo = 'Author';
}
?>
```

src/Controller/BooksController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
class BooksController extends AppController {
   var $name = 'Books';
   function index() {
      $this->Book->recursive = 1;
      $books = $this->Book->find('all');
      $this->set('books', $books);
   }
}
?>
```

src/Controller/AuthorsController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
class AuthorsController extends AppController {
   var $name = 'Authors';
   function index() {
      $this->Authors->recursive = 2;
      $authors = $this->Authors->find('all');
      $this->set('authors', $authors);
   }
}
?>
```

src/Templates/Authors/index.php

```
<?php foreach($authors as $author): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $author['Author']['name'] ?></h2>
    <hr />
    <h3>Book(s):</h3>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($author['Book'] as $book): ?>
        <li><?php echo $book['title'] ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The database authors and books table both contain data and were created using the following migrations:

```
<?php
use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class CreateAuthors extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * Change Method.
     *
     * More information on this method is available here:
     * http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#the-change-method
     * @return void
     */
    public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('authors');
        $table->addColumn('name', 'text', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('email', 'text', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('website', 'text', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->create();
    }
}
```

And

```
<?php
use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class CreateBooks extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * Change Method.
     *
     * More information on this method is available here:
     * http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#the-change-method
     * @return void
     */
    public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('books');
        $table->addColumn('isbn', 'text', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('title', 'text', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('description', 'text', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('author_id', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->create();
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: sure it's cake3? Seems cake2 code. If it's cake 2 i think that the association must be an array: `public $hasMany = array('Book')` but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: There's a lot of things wrong, I'd suggest that you head over to the docs, start with [**the tutorials**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html), and then check the database/controller/view sections, as all your model code, and also some of the controller/view code, is CakePHP 2.x based.

Comment: You tagged your issue under CakePHP 3 but It seems like you are coding all the CakePHP stuff in CakePHP 2. For your kind info, recursive has been removed from the CakePHP 3 and earlier version. Click on this link to know more https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/orm-migration.html#recursive-and-containablebehavior-removed